# How to reliably share a mongo database between 2 meteor applications on local machine?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've been struggling to *reliably* share a database between 2 different meteor applications (admin and client) on my local machine. I can get it to work sometimes but then others it won't connect for an entire day despite all my attempts and resetting db's, restarting machine, clearing cache, etc.

My question is what exactly are the steps in order to make this work reliably?

Here is what has worked at some times in the past for me:

Open up my Webstorm IDE for my meteor client application and in the terminal for the project I run: **meteor run**. Once a connection has been made I hit ctrl+c to kill the connection and switch to the meteor admin application and then I run: **MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor" meteor**

This has worked several times and both applications are sharing the same mongo database. However this is not reliable for me as some times after shutting down or closing Webstorm I cannot get them to both connect properly and share the same database. I originally thought I just needed to restart and or close webstorm's terminal sessions but this isn't reliable either. Any help would be very appreciated.

**Update**
I've also tried opening two separate terminal sessions and doing the following to no avail:

Terminal 1- client: meteor (this runs the client app as expected)
Terminal 1- client: ctrl+c to kill the running app

Terminal 2- admin: MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor" meteor (this fails to connect to the previous client database, fails to run the admin application and gives this error: W20151019-13:30:40.334(-5)? (STDERR) Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3001] )

Comment: Why do you bother with your IDE instead of firing up a MongoDB instance yourself?

Comment: I was just using Webstorms IDE and Terminal as it's convenient but I just tried the same steps with two terminal sessions and had no luck.

Comment: Can you please [edit] in what you did in two terminals and how it failed too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are truly "local" databases, then you shouldn't expect to be able to access them from each other.

A *local* MongoDB [database] is one that has been created in an "isClient" code block or within the /client folder hierarchy, using either no name, or null to define it, like so:

```
PlatypusCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

OTOH, if you give the collection a name, like so:

```
PlatypusCollection = new Mongo.Collection('platypus');
```

...(and put this code somewhere other than an "isClient" block or the "client" folder or a subfolder thereof), it will be a server-side collection that can be published by the server and subscribed to by clients. By default (via the autopublish and insecure packages), all server-side Collections are available to everyone.

### UPDATE

If you mean that you want to have two instances of the same Meteor app running simultaneously, you will need to have one of them run on a port other than 3000. From the command line, you'll need to do something like this:

```
meteor --port 3042
```

This may differ a little depending on the OS you're developing on (hint to the Meteor-monitors/masters administrating the StackOverflow Meteor-related tags: it might be worthwhile to have meteor-windows, meteor-linux, meteor-ios tags, or something similar).

By default, the first instance of your Meteor app will run on localhost:3000, but there's not enough room in that "town" for two apps to run simultaneously, so one has to "get out of Dodge."

Then (after making sure both are running on their own ports), the two Meteor app instances should both be able to access the same MongoDB database (provided it's not truly a *local* (Minimongo) database, as noted above).

Similar to how the first instance of a Meteor app runs by default on port 3000, the related MongoDB instance by default runs on port 3001, so don't give the second app instance that port number (unless you explicitly gave the MongoDB a different port number than the default).

Comment: To clarify what I'm looking to do, I want to 2 applications to share the same database on my local machine. If I create user "Bob Thompson" in one application then when I log into the other application I want to be able to see "Bob Thompson". I've done this using MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor" in the past but it hasn't been reliable so I must be missing the fundamentals on how to properly connect my 2 applications.

Comment: If you mean you want to have two instances of the same Meteor app running simultaneously, you will need to have one of them run on a port other than 3000. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Clay! I'm using a Mac and on my first app I ran meteor --port 3005. From what I understand this runs mongodb on port 3006. So, then on my second app I ran MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3006/meteor" meteor and everything worked. Note you could also run MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:3006/meteor" meteor and get the same results. I had been trying to run everything on port 3000 and it sounds like the lack of room may have caused my issue where it would work one day and not the next.